# Javascript won't work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I'm trying to build mobile responsiveness into the app my work is building. Unfortunately that means I can't share the code, but I'm running into a very strange problem no one at my office seems to understand.

We have a feature on our site similar to Typeform, where you press an OK button and the site scrolls to the next question. It's 100% javascript and works fine on desktop and iPhone. However, it's very inconsistent on android phones, working on few and not working on most. Because you can't really open dev tools on a phone, I can't sort out why. Google has not been helpful in me sorting out the solution. Has this happened to other people? Is there a direction someone can point me in that would help me sort it out?

Comment: Is this a native app with a WebView or a website running in the phone's browser?

Comment: I was just about to add that. :) This is in a phone browser. The issue persists on Chrome and whatever the default Android browser is.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Ohhhh this will be amazingly useful thank you!